# Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'm trying to say

> We stayed in an apartment. I thought that it was great because it was near the town.

This is what I have written:

> Wir sind in einer Wohnung geblieben. Ich denke, dass es prima war weil es in der Nähe von die Stadt war.

Is the grammar in sentence correct?

Comment: Please see the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. You would have to use "in der Nähe von *der* Stadt", because it is genitive. But most notably the "it was great" refers to the "apartment" and the German "Wohnung" is feminine, so you need "sie".

Your English sentence contains "thought", so it would be "dachte" in German, but probably that's up to you if you want to translate it that way. Here's a problem: If your sentence continues as "I thought it was ..., BUT" you have to use Konjunktiv.

Please also note that you need a comma before "weil" (it is a so-called Subjunktion).

So your sentence would be:

> Wir sind in einer Wohnung geblieben. Ich dachte, dass sie prima war, weil sie in der Nähe von der Stadt war.

But if you ask for a well-formed sentence I would recommend (also showing the other interpretation):

> Wir waren in einem Apartment untergebracht. Ich hielt es für sehr gut, weil es in der Nähe der Stadt lag, aber...

Comment: Thank you! Could I say, 'Ich habe sie prima gefunden' (because I need to stick to the perfect tense.)

Comment: @Sophia Although "prima" is colloquial and it sounds a bit awkward you could.

Comment: Does 'großartig' sound better? Or is that still quite colloquial?

Comment: @Sophia "großartig" is not colloquial. Probably you should use that. But the perfect tense still sounds awkward.

Comment: Thank you! Sadly this is for an exam and it has to be written mostly in the perfect tense while I would prefer to write more natural German the examiners would rather see awkward sentences in the perfect tense for some reason.